# Can i use different wallpaper in my dual monitor?

Tags: wallpaper

I am using dual monitor for my work, currently running mint 18, Now i have question can i use different wallpaper on my both monitor in loki ?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this application? :)
[Multi Monitor Tweaks](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/10/ubuntu-multi-monitor-tweaks-full-screen.html)

It seems to be a tutorial for exactly the thing you want. ;)

Answer (score 1):

There is no option in Elementary for that, but you can use a 3rd party program such as nitrogen.

```
sudo apt-get install nitrogen
```

Comment: Nitrogen is available via AppCenter, it would make more sense to recommend that method of installation instead of the Terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Nitrogen doesn't seem to work in elementary OS for some reason. Or should i say, the app itself works and you can set the different wallpapers, but then the configuration made in nitrogen doesn't work.

i think a way to override the desktop settings in "system settings" to allow nitrogen to set the wallpapers is what is needed. unfortunately im looking for that solution myself...so far to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience ,Nitrogen doesnt work only dual monitor wallpaper settings in elementary OS.

After setting Nitrogen, open dconf-editor and go to

> org > gnome > desktop > background

Then turn off show-desktop-icons and change picture-options to wallpaper.

I sucseeded to activate Nitrogen settings.